# What's wrong with this multiline PCRE capture?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

PHP:

```
$x = preg_match (
    '/^([.\\n\\r]*)\\n\\n/m',
    "a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf",
    $m);

print "x=$x, m=";
print_r ($m);
```

This outputs

```
x=0, m=Array (
)
```

I expected

```
x=1, m=Array (
        [0] => a
    b
    c

    d
    e
    f
        [1] => a
    b
    c
)
```

I am using the `/m` modifier. Variations work on this when the captured string contains no new lines. Why doesn't it work as it is?

Comment: The `.` matches a literal dot inside a character class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$x = preg_match (
    '/^(.*)\n\n.*/sm',
    "a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf",
    $m);

print "x=$x, m=";
print_r ($m);
```

You don't need all that escaping plus you can use the s modifier to make . match newlines.

The above outputs what you were expecting, whether or not it solves your wider problem is, of course, a different matter - it's my best guess at what you were trying to do.